# 400 () status error in our application

Tags: java, spring

We created a new domain and deployed a new war file , but when i login into my application, the data was not getting from the database.

**Getting 400() status error**

In our application we are using spring security & Annotations,we have the @preAuthorize annotaions in controller class.

When i tried, i got the where issue was raised and use to delete the @preAuthorize annotaion in one particular method in controller class,and deployed a new war file.
I got the data of that particular method,but in my application i have so many @preAuthorize annotaions.
How can i resolve this issue can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: 40x code  means client was able to communicate with a given server

Answer (score -1):

If you want to secure web controllers, the better idea is to use  and  that are bound to specific urls rather than methods in controllers and work pretty well.

```
...

<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
```

Comment: Yes i know that,but previously we deployed the same war file in tomcat but the domain was different. In that domain we got the data from database and also there was no issue. I access the application and got the data for every module.

Comment: But now it was not getting the data for new domain,the war file  was same.

Comment: try moving the pre post annotation on service layer